# Is there a local System.Text.Json cache per assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, system.text.json

I am experiencing a strange problem with serialization using `System.Text.Json` in version 6.0.8: serialization time depends on my assembly name.

I have a console app (net48) that only contains the following and exits:

```cs
var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize("Hello, World!");
timer.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.ToString());
```

For some reason the time it takes to serialize the string depends on the assembly name. I have somehow "contaminated" an assembly name. If I use that name, then the serialization will take around 4 seconds. For something that is already a string! If I just change the assembly name, the result is some hundred milliseconds. I don't need to  recompile - I can take the exact same binary that took 4s to execute, rename it, and it will run in 2-300ms.

I have tried:

- **Moving the app to a different machine**: If I move the assembly with the bad name to a different machine, or run it from the Windows sandbox, it runs fast as well. No issue here.
- **Restarting**: Didn't make a difference.
- **Using Newtonsoft**: I don't experience this issue with Newtonsoft. I have so far only experienced it with System.Text.Json.
- **Looping over the Serialization**: It is only the first invokation that is very slow - even if I change the input in every iteration.
- **.NET Core 6.0**: Doesn't have this behavior.
- **Use Version 7.0.3**: I couldn't reproduce the issue with this version.

Since the issue for this assembly is only observable on machine and it survives a restart, I assume there is some cache on my machine that has become corrupted for that assembly name. But basically I don't know what is going on... Any good ideas?

Comment: System.Text.Json was designed to work with .NET Core, and was merely backported to .NET Framework.  Can you test on .NET Core to see if the problem is reproducible there?

Comment: Also, you should take a look at Eric Lippert's 4-part series on benchmarking mistakes ([one](https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/), [two](https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/21/benchmarking-mistakes-part-two/), [three](https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/09/benchmarking-mistakes-part-three/), [four](https://ericlippert.com/2013/08/19/benchmarking-mistakes-part-four/)) to make sure your measurements are really valid. ...

Comment: ... Because it may be that the difference is entirely due to the **first** call to `JsonSerializer.Serialize()` because multiple DLLs need to be loaded that are already loaded into the GAC on other computers and for less esoteric builds than .NET 4.8 + System.Text.Json.  Is the problem reproducible on **every** call to `JsonSerializer`, or just the first call?

Comment: Also, what specific versions of System.Text.Json and all its [dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/) (Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, System.Buffers, System.Memory, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, System.Text.Encodings.Web and so on) are you using?  Are you using the exact same versions on the computer where the problem reproduces vs a computer where it does not?

Comment: @dbc, You are right - it is only the first call - but still I don't understand the dependency to the assembly name. I can run the slow assembly - then take the exact same binary, rename it and then it is more than 10 times faster. I haven't read Lippert's articles yet, but it is a console app, that prints out and exists. The difference between 200-300ms and 4000ms is very visible.

Comment: @dbc, I tried it out with .net 6, and that didn't have the problem. But no matter what framework it was designed for, it is still very strange, that the behavior depends on the assembly name.

Comment: My recommendation would be to stick with Json.NET in .NET Framework 4.x and only use System.Text.Json starting with .NET 5.  (It was pretty buggy and limited in .NET Core 3.x).  Or you could use Json.NET in all versions, it's not like it's deprecated or anything.  Beyond that I can only suggest that you profile your .NET 4.8 + System.Text.Json console app to see what is going on.  My guess is still that the poor performance has something to do with DLL loading and/or caching, but that's only a guess.  Good luck!